# How do I fix this Sentry Zone mismatch error?

Tags: flutter, dart, sentry, dart-isolates

Framework / SDK versions:

```
Flutter: 3.10.4
Dart: 3.0.3
```

Here goes my `main()` code:

```
Future<void> main() async {
  //debugPaintSizeEnabled = true;
  //BindingBase.debugZoneErrorsAreFatal = true;
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  EasyLocalization.ensureInitialized()
      .then((value) => Fimber.plantTree(DebugTree()))
      .then((value) => SentryFlutter.init(
            (options) {
              options.dsn = '***';
              // Set tracesSampleRate to 1.0 to capture 100% of transactions for performance monitoring.
              // We recommend adjusting this value in production.
              options.tracesSampleRate = 1.0;
              //options.attachScreenshot = true;
            },
            appRunner: () => runApp(
              EasyLocalization(
                supportedLocales: const [Locale('en', 'US'), Locale('de', 'DE')],
                path: '../assets/translations/',
                fallbackLocale: const Locale('en', 'US'),
                assetLoader: const CodegenLoader(),
                child: MyApp(),
              ),
            ),
          ));
}
```

And I am getting the following error, that I can't locate:

```
Exception caught by Flutter framework =====================================================
The following assertion was thrown during runApp:
Zone mismatch.

The Flutter bindings were initialized in a different zone than is now being used. This will likely cause confusion and bugs as any zone-specific configuration will inconsistently use the configuration of the original binding initialization zone or this zone based on hard-to-predict factors such as which zone was active when a particular callback was set.
It is important to use the same zone when calling `ensureInitialized` on the binding as when calling `runApp` later.
To make this warning fatal, set BindingBase.debugZoneErrorsAreFatal to true before the bindings are initialized (i.e. as the first statement in `void main() { }`).
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/patch/core_patch.dart 942:28   get current
packages/flutter/src/foundation/binding.dart 497:29                  <fn>
packages/flutter/src/foundation/binding.dart 501:14                  debugCheckZone
packages/flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart 1080:17                    runApp
packages/ens_price_calculator/main.dart 52:30                        <fn>
packages/sentry/src/sentry.dart 136:26                               <fn>
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/patch/async_patch.dart 45:50   <fn>
dart-sdk/lib/async/zone.dart 1407:47                                 _rootRunUnary
dart-sdk/lib/async/zone.dart 1308:19                                 runUnary
dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 147:18                           handleValue
dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 784:44                           handleValueCallback
dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 813:13                           _propagateToListeners
dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 584:5                            [_completeWithValue]
dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 657:7                            <fn>
dart-sdk/lib/async/zone.dart 1399:13                                 _rootRun
dart-sdk/lib/async/zone.dart 1301:19                                 run
dart-sdk/lib/async/zone.dart 1209:7                                  runGuarded
dart-sdk/lib/async/zone.dart 1249:23                                 callback
dart-sdk/lib/async/schedule_microtask.dart 40:11                     _microtaskLoop
dart-sdk/lib/async/schedule_microtask.dart 49:5                      _startMicrotaskLoop
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/patch/async_patch.dart 177:15  <fn>
=================================================================================================
```

Has anyone been able to get rid of this? Any suggestions appreciated.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can find the solution at https://github.com/getsentry/sentry-dart/tree/main/flutter#usage.

`ensureInitialized` has to be called within the `runZonedGuarded`

```dart
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';
import 'package:sentry_flutter/sentry_flutter.dart';

Future<void> main() async {
  // creates a zone
  await runZonedGuarded(() async {
    WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
    // Initialize other stuff here...

    await SentryFlutter.init(
      (options) {
        options.dsn = 'https://example@sentry.io/add-your-dsn-here';
      },
    );
    // or here
    runApp(MyApp());
  }, (exception, stackTrace) async {
    await Sentry.captureException(exception, stackTrace: stackTrace);
  });
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I will try it when I will get to work.Do you know how to you find the library that causes the error? Just.in case I will run into a similar error in.the future.

Comment: I have implemented what you have suggested, but sadly nothing has changed https://gist.github.com/Turbozanik/8f90fd1e68111f23f3afa8aba91a7e75

Comment: @void your runApp() needs to be outside of Sentry.init, just like I did in my example above

Comment: This does not work for me when I invoke `runZoneGuarded` outside the `main` function. Something like this: `main() { // init configs; customRunApp();}` and this `customRunApp` function runs the zone

Comment: `runZonedGuarded` isn't used any longer. Scroll down to see my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77578694/6513173

Answer (score 1):

You can find the solution at [@Medium](https://medium.com/@madhanrkv10/flutter-zone-mismatch-error-solved-without-using-external-package-sentry-b7d1fe3fdd62) , To solve Zone mismatch error without using external package.

```
Future<void> main() async {


runZonedGuarded<Future<void>>(() async {

WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  runApp(const MyApp());
  FlutterError.onError = (FlutterErrorDetails details) {
   FlutterError.presentError(details);
  };
  ErrorWidget.builder = (FlutterErrorDetails details) {
   return Scaffold(
     appBar: AppBar(
       backgroundColor: Colors.red,
       title: const Text('An error occurred'),
     ),
     body: Center(child: Text(details.toString())),
   );
  };
 }, 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Folks per zone mismatch breaking changes
https://docs.flutter.dev/release/breaking-changes/zone-errors#:~:text=Flutter%20requires%20(and%20has%20always,has%20not%20detected%20such%20mismatches.

You cannot run GuardedZones any more for flutter apps as it has been depreciated and also Sentry itself has change to the new form of not being wrapped in GuardedZones.

Comment: so what's the solution?

Comment: @PimvanderHeijden same question. I suffer with Crashlytics as well due to this. I am using `runGuardedZone` in a helper function called by `main` method and get the error zone

Comment: @KristiJorgji scroll up to see my answer, https://stackoverflow.com/a/77578694/6513173

Answer (score 0):

From Flutter 3.3 onwards `runZonedGuarded` is not uses anymore to run Sentry normally. This should be sufficient, at time of writing:

```
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';
import 'package:sentry_flutter/sentry_flutter.dart';

Future<void> main() async {
  await SentryFlutter.init(
    (options) {
      options.dsn = 'https://example@sentry.io/add-your-dsn-here';
    },
    // Init your App.
    appRunner: () => runApp(MyApp()),
  );
}
```

Read: https://github.com/getsentry/sentry-dart/tree/main/flutter#usage