# Flutter zone mismatch not resolved by moving ensureInitialized call

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm building a flutter mobile app. Whenever I start the app, I get the following error message.

```
══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY FLUTTER FRAMEWORK ╞═════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following assertion was thrown during runApp:
Zone mismatch.
The Flutter bindings were initialized in a different zone than is now being used. This will likely
cause confusion and bugs as any zone-specific configuration will inconsistently use the
configuration of the original binding initialization zone or this zone based on hard-to-predict
factors such as which zone was active when a particular callback was set.
It is important to use the same zone when calling `ensureInitialized` on the binding as when calling
`runApp` later.
To make this warning fatal, set BindingBase.debugZoneErrorsAreFatal to true before the bindings are
initialized (i.e. as the first statement in `void main() { }`).

When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
#0      BindingBase.debugCheckZone.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/foundation/binding.dart:497:29)
#1      BindingBase.debugCheckZone (package:flutter/src/foundation/binding.dart:502:6)
#2      runApp (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:1080:18)
#3      main.<anonymous closure> (package:na0826/main.dart:132:7)
#8      main (package:na0826/main.dart:120:5)
<asynchronous suspension>
(elided 4 frames from dart:async)
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
```

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76472459/how-do-i-fix-this-sentry-zone-mismatch-error) that seems to address the issue. I'm not using Sentry, but other than that my code looks decently similar. I tried moving `WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();` into the function passed into `runZonedGuarded`, but I still get the same error. I'm not running `WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();` anywhere else in my code other than inside `runZonedGuarded`. I'm getting the error on both iOS and Android emulators. I also tried restarting the app with `flutter clean` -> `flutter pub get` -> `flutter run` with no success. `flutter doctor` shows that I have no issues. Here is my full main function.

```
void main() async {
  bool hasFailed = false;

  try {
    // various setup functions
    setupLogging();
    await setupHive();
    _setupJellyfinApiData();
    await FlutterDownloader.initialize(ignoreSsl: false);
    await _setupDownloadsHelper();
    await _setupAudioServiceHelper();
    await Firebase.initializeApp();
    Get.put(UtilsLogic(), permanent: true);
    Get.put(NetworkLogic(), permanent: true);
    Get.put(DownloadLogic(), permanent: true);
    await initializePlatformSpecifics();
    await networkLogic.hasConnection();
    FirebaseNotifications.setUpFirebase();
  } catch (e) {
    hasFailed = true;
    runApp(NA0826ErrorApp(
      error: e,
    ));
  }
  SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([DeviceOrientation.portraitUp]);
  if (!hasFailed) {
    final flutterLogger = Logger("Flutter");
    runZonedGuarded(() async {
      WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized(); // I moved this line into runZonedGuarded. This didn't resolve the error.

      FlutterError.onError = (errorDetails) {
        FirebaseCrashlytics.instance.recordFlutterFatalError(errorDetails);
      };

      PlatformDispatcher.instance.onError = (error, stack) {
        FirebaseCrashlytics.instance.recordError(error, stack, fatal: true);
        return true;
      };

      runApp(const MyApp());
    }, (error, stackTrace) {
      flutterLogger.severe(error, null, stackTrace);
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: https://github.com/newrelic/newrelic-flutter-agent/issues/64#issuecomment-1798671957